# Serverless framework deploy does not install node dependancies

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, serverless-framework, aws-serverless

I have a very simple node app which I got from the serverless examples: https://github.com/serverless/examples/tree/master/aws-node-express-api. I deployed with:

```
serverless deploy
```

serverless.yml is:

```
service: aws-node-express-api

frameworkVersion: '2'


provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs12.x
  lambdaHashingVersion: '20201221'

functions:
  api:
    handler: handler.handler
    events:
      - http:
          path: /
          method: ANY
      - http:
          path: /{proxy+}
          method: ANY
```

handler.js is:

```
const serverless = require("serverless-http");
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

app.get("/", (req, res, next) => {
  return res.status(200).json({
    message: "Hello from root!",
  });
});

app.get("/hello", (req, res, next) => {
  return res.status(200).json({
    message: "Hello from path!",
  });
});

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  return res.status(404).json({
    error: "Not Found",
  });
});

module.exports.handler = serverless(app);
```

package.json is:

```
{
  "name": "aws-node-express-api",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "serverless-http": "^2.7.0"
  }
}
```

When I run a CURL, I get:

```
{"message": "Internal server error"}
```

When I check the logs I see:

```
{
    "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
    "errorMessage": "Error: Cannot find module 'serverless-http'\nRequire stack:\n- /var/task/handler.js\n- /var/runtime/UserFunction.js\n- /var/runtime/index.js",
    "stack": [
        "Runtime.ImportModuleError: Error: Cannot find module 'serverless-http'",
        "Require stack:",
        "- /var/task/handler.js",
        "- /var/runtime/UserFunction.js",
        "- /var/runtime/index.js",
        "    at _loadUserApp (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:100:13)",
        "    at Object.module.exports.load (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:140:17)",
        "    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/index.js:43:30)",
        "    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)",
        "    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)",
        "    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)",
        "    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)",
        "    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:60:12)",
        "    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47"
    ]
}
```

I went to the Lambda function on AWS and I see:

[image]

So you can see there is no node_modules folder. I dont want to push up the node_modules folder, I expect the dependancies to get installed automtically (Im pretty sure this happened before when I last create a serverless node function). But it's not getting installed. How can I ensure dependancies get installed?

Answer (score 0):

`npm install` is not ran automatically with the Serverless Framework.

AWS provides a minimal node environment, but the only the aws-sdk is [included](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-package.html).

You'll need to run `npm install` before deploying.